# mysql not allowing escape characters in an insert query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

0.25 version with php and phpmyadmin Now I am using it to insert rows in to database when I print the insert query I get

```
 INSERT INTO `anqui_ira_solok_account_maintenance_forms` 
 (`mailing_address_street_address`, `mailing_address_city`,`mailing_address_state`,`mailing_address_zip_code`,`updated_date`, 
`submitted_date`,`created_date`) 
VALUES ('test \"and\" test','test','test \"11\"','452001','2021-06-29 
03:39:17','2021-06-29 03:39:17','2021-06-29')
```

As you can see I am escaping the double quote with special characters `\` but when I run this query from either the app or from phpmyadmin sql option the escape characters are removed and I get values like `test "and" test` I should get `test \"and\" test`.

I have changed the engine from myIsam to innodb and collation to `utf8_general_ci`

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=247 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

But to no avail If I try to update a individual column with escape value it works but not in an insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to escape the *escape* character.  So this should do what you want:

```
VALUES ('test \\"and\\" test','test', 'test \\"11\\"',
        '452001', '2021-06-29 03:39:17',
        '2021-06-29 03:39:17', '2021-06-29'
       )
```

Comment: yes that works I have to escape the escape characters